# Factorization in Dedekind domains

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative,  Dedekind (and therefore Noetherian) ring with $1$. Let $I$
be a non-prime ideal of $R$, and let $a,b$ be elements of $R$ such that
$a\not\in I,b\not\in I$ but $ab\in I$. Let $\cal P$ be the set of prime ideals appearing in the Dedekind factorization of $(I,a)$ or $(I,b)$. Then $\cal P$ is finite, and I ask : is it always true that some ideal in $\cal P$ must appear in the
Dedekind factorization of $I$ ?

If true, this would provide a theoretical "algorithm" to compute
 the Dedekind factorization of any ideal of such a ring $R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"To divide is to contain."

Thus, if $P$ divides $(I,a)$ then $P$ contains $(I,a)$ and so  $P$ contains $I$. This means that $P$ divides $I$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is perhaps worthwile to mention that "to divide is to contain" is proved at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103692/divides-means-contains-for-dedekind-domains-by-treating-pids-and-localising

Comment: @EwanDelanoy, I wonder what role is played by $b$ ...

Comment: No role at all, it just appears naturally when you try to use the non-prime character of $I$