# Does this characterize rings in which every ideal is principal?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

(All my rings are commutative.)

Let $R$ denote a ring. Then given ideals $I,J$ and $K$ of $R$, from $J=IK$, we may deduce that $J \subseteq I$. In some rings, the converse doesn't necessarily hold. For example, let $R = \mathbb{R}[x,y]$. Then:

$$xR \subseteq xR+yR$$

but there is no ideal $K$ of $R$ satisfying $xR = (xR+yR)K$

However, suppose that every ideal of $R$ is principal. Then from $J \subseteq I,$ we can conclude the existence of $K$ satisfying $J=IK$. For example, in the integers, from $12\mathbb{Z} \subseteq 2\mathbb{Z}$, we may deduce that $12\mathbb{Z} = (2\mathbb{Z})K$ for some ideal $K$, namely $K = 6\mathbb{Z}$.

> **Question.** Does this characterize rings in which every ideal is principal? Explicitly: suppose we're given a ring $R$ such that for all ideals $I,J$ of $R$, from $J \subseteq I$ we may deduce the existence of an ideal $K$ of $R$ such that $J=IK$. Does it follow that every ideal of $R$ is principal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not follow that $R$ is a principal ideal ring, not even if $R$ is a domain.

"To contain is to divide" is true in every Dedekind domain, but not all Dedekind domains are principal ideal domains. One example is $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{−5}]$.

Comment: How do we know its true in every Dedekind domain?

Comment: @goblin, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103692/divides-means-contains-for-dedekind-domains-by-treating-pids-and-localising.

Comment: Okay. Do you know if "Dedekind domain" characterizes such rings?

Comment: @goblin, I don't. Perhaps you could ask a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

The Noetherian domains which have this property are precisely the Dedekind domains: see e.g. Proposition 20.9 of [my commutative algebra notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral.pdf).  One way to say it is that this condition buys precisely that all ideals are *locally* principal, not that they are principal.

What about an arbitrary commutative ring?  Certainly rings in which each ideal is principal have this property.  Off the top of my head I don't know whether requiring that every ideal be locally principal is either necessary or sufficient.

Comment: By a "domain", what precisely do you mean? In particular, are your domains commutative?

Comment: @goblin:  I mean precisely a commutative ring without nonzero zero-divisors.  (Was it not clear that we are in the context of commutative algebra?  You mentioned it and so did I.)

Comment: It was 80% clear.

Comment: Your notes assume that $R$ is a Noetherian domain: I assume that is what you mean here?

Comment: @goblin: That's a good catch, thanks.  When I wrote my answer I was thinking this was true for all domains, but upon reflection I believe there are non-Noetherian domains with this property.